# ¿como insertar datos de una tabla con varios registros en una con registros únicos?

Tags: sql

A ver si me se explicar tengo la tabla1 con varias columnas pero la columna **numeroID** es única no se repite.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero ir añadiendo columnas con la fecha a la tabla según han cambiado de un estado a otro (tengo 7 estados diferentes) y tengo la tabla2 con los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero aquí el numero de ID se repite

El resultado que querria seria una tabla que fuera la tabla1 y añadiendo tantas columnas como cambios de estado y fecha.

Gracias

el resultado final que quiero es una tabla del estilo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de como quieres que quede tu tabla, osea el resultado esperado. Para poder entenderte mejor.

Comment: hola ricardo he añadido la tabla resultado que quiero conseguir en la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debemos procurar es que no exista información repetida, ayudando que no existan problemas como que en la tabla principal diga que el estado actual es 2, pero en la tabla historica diga que el estado final es 7.

Te propongo la siguiente estructura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda tabla será la histórica y tendrá 2 campos clave añadiendo la fecha del cambio en el primary key.

El campo de estado anterior al cambio se lo puede obviar porque lo obtendrías revisando el anterior registro de la tabla tabla1_hist.

Comment: las tablas las tengo, lo que necesito es una consulta que me devuelva una tabla unica.